# How to make Android application update mandatory?

Tags: android, google-play, updates

Is there a way that I can check my application update in Google Play using code at application start up and make application update mandatory?

Comment: May be these link help you to establish your mandatory app update through your servers. Possible you can recommend  your user to update immediately from Play store http://code.google.com/p/auto-update-apk-client/

Answer (score 1):

This code checks for updates of the Activity once a day and in the background. If an update (higher version than current) is found, it opens a Dialog and asks the user to open the market.

### Code is somewhat like these :-->

`http://mycompany.com/update` pointing to your server site where you can put text file or watever to get the latest version and compare it for the newer version. On the basis of comparison enforced them for update

```
public class Test extends Activity {
private Handler mHandler;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.front);
    mHandler = new Handler();

    /* Get Last Update Time from Preferences */
    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0);
    lastUpdateTime =  prefs.getLong("lastUpdateTime", 0);

    /* Should Activity Check for Updates Now? */
    if ((lastUpdateTime + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) < System.currentTimeMillis()) {

        /* Save current timestamp for next Check*/
        lastUpdateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();            
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
        editor.putLong("lastUpdateTime", lastUpdateTime);
        editor.commit();        

        /* Start Update */            
        checkUpdate.start();
    }
}

/* This Thread checks for Updates in the Background */
private Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            URL updateURL = new URL("http://my.company.com/update");                
            URLConnection conn = updateURL.openConnection(); 
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

            int current = 0;
            while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
                 baf.append((byte)current);
            }

            /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
            final String s = new String(baf.toByteArray());         

            /* Get current Version Number */
            int curVersion = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your.app.id", 0).versionCode;
            int newVersion = Integer.valueOf(s);

            /* Is a higher version than the current already out? */
            if (newVersion > curVersion) {
                /* Post a Handler for the UI to pick up and open the Dialog */
                mHandler.post(showUpdate);
            }                
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
};

/* This Runnable creates a Dialog and asks the user to open the Market */ 
private Runnable showUpdate = new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
        new AlertDialog.Builder(Test.this)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setTitle("Update Available")
        .setMessage("An update for is available!\\n\\nOpen Android Market and see the details?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:your.app.id"));
                        startActivity(intent);
                }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        /* User clicked Cancel */
                }
        })
        .show();
       }
};
```

}`